# Spresense-Arduinoのスケッチ例PCM_captureをモノラル録音（AS_CHANNEL_MONO）の際のデータ構造がわかりません。

Tags: spresense, データ構造, audio

Spresense-Arduino のスケッチ例 pcm_captureを参考にマイクからモノラルで50サンプルデータを取り出し、最終的にはRMS値で標記したいと思っています。

スケッチ例 pcm_captureの中にある以下のコードがキャプチャした音声データの中身を表示していることはわかるのですが、具体的にどのような構造で音声データが格納されているかがわかりません。

AS_CHANNEL_MONOで取り出した場合、s_buffer(a1,a2,a3,a4)とするとa2とa4に00又はffが表示されます。本来、データがa2,a3,a4に存在しない場合は00と標記されると思うのですが、原因がわかりません。

1chで音声データを取り出し、RMS値標記するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
printf("Size %d [%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x ...]\n",
     size,
     s_buffer[0],
     s_buffer[1],
     s_buffer[2],
     s_buffer[3],
     s_buffer[4],
     s_buffer[5],
     s_buffer[6],
     s_buffer[7]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

類似の質問を見つけました。
[https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55107/spresense-arduino-のスケッチ例-pcm-captureの音声データ構造について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55107/spresense-arduino-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E4%BE%8B-pcm-capture%E3%81%AE%E9%9F%B3%E5%A3%B0%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E6%A7%8B%E9%80%A0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
ここの回答に載っている16bit音声データの型を`uint16_t`-->`int16_t`にして、データ構造は符号付き16bitで並んでいるだけなので、

モノラル1chのRMS値は、こんな感じで求められると思います。

```c
  struct channel_bit16 {
   int16_t micA;
  };

  struct channel_bit16 *mic_data = (struct channel_bit16 *)s_buffer;
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    sum += mic_data[i].micA * mic_data[i].micA;
  }
  double rms = sqrt((double)sum/50);
  printf("%.3lf\n", rms);
```

Comment: 回答していただきありがとうございます。サンプルコードもご提示いただき、とても分かりやすいです。教えていただいた内容を参考にして試してみます。