# Spresense-Arduino のスケッチ例 pcm_captureのデータ構造について

Tags: spresense

Spresense-Arduino のスケッチ例 pcm_captureを用いてマイクに入力されたデータをcsvに書き込み，
後々処理することができたらなと考えています．

今現在，モノラルでマイクAからの入力されたデータの表示をしたいのですが，
PCMで取り出したデータには，WAVのRIFFフォーマットのような形で，ヘッダーかフッターに音声とは別の
固定のデータが入っているのでしょうか．
もし，入っているのだとすれば，何バイト分どの箇所にデータがあるのでしょうか．

また，うまくいけば，ステレオでマイクAマイクBからのデータの入力されたデータの表示もしたいのですが，
その場合のデータ構造はどのようになるのでしょうか．

分かる方いらっしゃいましたら，ご教授いただきたいです．

Comment: [Spresense-Arduino のスケッチ例 pcm\_captureの音声データ構造について - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55107/spresense-arduino-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E4%BE%8B-pcm-capture%E3%81%AE%E9%9F%B3%E5%A3%B0%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E6%A7%8B%E9%80%A0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)